# kafka log-compaction consuming data

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I'm reading about log compaction in the latest release of kafka and am curious how this impacts consumers. Do consumers work the same as they ever did, or is there a new process for getting all the latest values?

With 'standard' Kafka topics, I use a consumer group to maintain a pointer to the most recent values. But if Kafka is keeping values based on keys instead of time, I'm wondering how consumer groups will work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It does not effect how consumers work. If you are only interested in the latest value per key and read the whole topic, you might still see "duplicates" for a key (if not all duplicates got eliminated, or new messages got written after last compaction run) and thus you only care about the latest value per key.

About consumer groups: When a topic gets compacted, there are "holes" in the range of valid offsets. While you are consuming a topic regularly, you will skip over those automatically.

From https://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#design_compactionbasics

> Note also that all offsets remain valid positions in the log, even if the message with that offset has been compacted away; in this case this position is indistinguishable from the next highest offset that does appear in the log. For example, in the picture above the offsets 36, 37, and 38 are all equivalent positions and a read beginning at any of these offsets would return a message set beginning with 38.

Answer (score 0):

According to my knowledge, when Kafka receives 'ack', it updates its pointer/offset. So when it receives ack of 5th message (for example), it assumes that all messages before 5 & 5th one as well have been processed successfully. Similarly it updates its offset. 
[This small application](https://github.com/bkimminich/apache-kafka-book-examples/blob/master/src/test/kafka/consumer/MultiThreadHLConsumer.java) describes usage of Consumers with grouping.

Answer (score 0):

Log Compaction triggers only for the passive log segments.

The file in which the data are currently written to -- Active log segments. Using these properties, 'log.roll.ms', 'log.segment.bytes' - an active log segments can be rolled to passive log segments.

While reading the data from the topic, consumer should take care to get the latest value for a key from the active log segment.

(e.g) In the active log segment, records will be stored like:
a. K1 - V1 (addition)
b. K1 - V2 (updation)
c. K1 - NULL (Deletion)

You can find more details about how Log compaction works [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Log+Compaction).